# Accessing elements located by custom locator strategy with Javascript

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

I have following issue:

- I have a checkbox which is hidden and there is another layer used to make it nice and shiny
- I can easily change its value by accessing its ID however I also need to access this element using my custom locator which uses xpath (that has to stay variable)

So, here's my script:

```
Custom Select Checkbox    id=my_checkbox        #that works fine
Custom Select Checkbox    customLocatorStrat    #that doesn't work at all

*** Keywords ***
Custom Select Checkbox
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${timeout}=${global_timeout}
    Execute Javascript    document.getElementById("${resultLocator}").checked = true;
    OR
    ${el}.checked = true;     #need to get the ${el} variable if the ${locator is not an id}


My Custom Locator
    [Arguments]    ${criteria}    ${tag}    ${constraints}
    ...     #assembling xpath
    ${el}=    Get Webelements    xpath=${path}
    [Return]    ${el}
```

There is no issue with the locator strategy - it workes fine. I only need to use it/force it in my Custom Select Checkbox keyword. I need to get the ${el} variable and considering there's more than one Custom Locator keyword calling it directly will not work for me. Any idea how to do this please? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom locators in the selenium2library require activation through the `Add Location Strategy` [[Doc]](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Add%20Location%20Strategy). This seems to me to be the missing from your example.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    Add Location Strategy   custom  Custom Locator Strategy
    Page Should Contain Element custom=my_id

*** Keywords ***
Custom Locator Strategy 
    [Arguments]    ${browser}    ${criteria}    ${tag}    ${constraints}
    ${retVal}=    Execute Javascript    return
window.document.getElementById('${criteria}');      
    [Return]    ${retVal}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
${el}=     Run Keyword If  '${locator}'!='my_checkbox'    My Custom Locator   ${criteria}    ${tag}    ${constraints}
```

You can get the variable before executing ${el}.checked = true;

Comment: Thing is that I cannot afford to call the locator strategy as there is more than one.

Comment: then instead of  [Return]    ${el}......
You can set it as test variable.

Comment: How can I reuse the webelement ${el} in Javascript script then?

Comment: if I do: Execute Javascript    ${el}.checked = true; it fails

Comment: So if locator is an id ..Then you need to run dis Execute Javascript    document.getElementById("${resultLocator}").checked = true; ....else  Execute Javascript   ${el}.checked = true;   .........Right?

Comment: Which is what I cannot do - as it has to be able to handle custom locators as well :)