# Automation on Ag-grid using Robot Framework

Tags: angular, automated-tests, robotframework, ag-grid

We have an UI built on ag-grid. There are lot of challenges regarding locating the elements as it doesn't have IDs and class names are very confusing. Below is an example. Please suggest me ways with which I can overcome these, If there are any materials or link please do share. Thanks in advance.

**Ques)** I want to fetch the data that is below 'Income' header. Previously, I have worked on the application in which the rows/data will be child elements of the 'Income' header, but , now, it's a different case. The tags are located irrespective to the 'Income' header (they are not the child elements of 'Income'). Attachment: [image: Header and Data] Shows Header and the data under it.

Please suggest me an approach which I follow. Also, that would be helpful for me to create a Generic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the grid is a predictable object, there is structure to it, even if it's not obvious at first. If your desire is to create a generic function for the [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) then I'd recommend porting their testing library functions found in [ag-Grid Testing Utilities](https://github.com/seanlandsman/ag-grid-testing/blob/master/dist/ag-grid.utils.js) (100 lines) to Python. The library use is explained here: [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-testing/#gsc.tab=0).

Alternatively you can load the library as a whole using the keywords: [Get File](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20File) followed by [Execute Javascript](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Execute%20Javascript) of the file contents concatenated with the command you want to execute in the JS file.

However, it seems that it revolves mostly around this function for getting the locator:

```
getCssSelectorForRowAndCol = function (row, col, additionalSelector) {
   additionalSelector = additionalSelector || '';
   return "div[row-id=\"" + row + "\"] div[col-id=\"" + col + "\"] " + additionalSelector;
};
```

So this should allow you to create a custom function, or even a custom locator strategy. For a short example have at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737729/accessing-elements-located-by-custom-locator-strategy-with-javascript/45743216#45743216).

**EDIT**: In response to the question below for an example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

Test Setup        Start Browser
Test Teardown     Close Browser
Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Example Get Values
    ${cell_value_row_2}    Get Cell Value Test    name         2
    Log To Console    Cell value for Name in Row 2: [${cell_value_row_2}]

    ${cell_value_row_3}    Get Cell Value Test    mobile    3
    Log To Console    Cell value for mobile in Row 3: [${cell_value_row_3}]  

*** Keywords ***
Get Cell Value Test
    [Arguments]    ${colum_name}    ${row_number}=1
    ${get_Text}    Get Text    xpath=//div[@row-id="${row_number}"]/div[@col-id="${colum_name}"]
    [Return]    ${get_Text}

Start Browser
    Open Browser    https://www.ag-grid.com/example-runner/angular.php?section=angular-getting-started&example=rich-grid-example&fontawesome=1&bootstrap=1&enterprise=1&grid=%7B%22theme%22%3A%22ag-theme-fresh%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22enterprise%22%3A1%7D    Chrome
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//div[@class="ag-body-container"]
```

Should result in the following lines on the command line:

```
Cell value for Name in Row 2: [Emily Braxton]
Cell value for mobile in Row 3: [+8710 846 6100 158]
```

Comment: thnaks @A. Kootstra. As I am new to this framework,  I couldn't implement what you have suggested. Can u please suggest me some steps or with an example.

Comment: The example which you have given obviously explains how to get the text of any cell providing "column Name". But, in my case the situation is different. I don't want to provide the 'column' or 'row' number in the function because, the number of rows and columns, and its location is not fixed. i.e: It's not sure that tags which contain data for any header will be the child elements. Also, I couldn't figure out any reference tag so that I can fetch data w.r.t its Headers.

My requirement is: I will provide the 'Header' name and it will fetch all data which is under it.

Comment: In the online demo the grandparent of the tag holding the header value contains the id of the column. However, in the attached screenshot this is lacking. As the code examples are similar, but some of the tag names are different I'm suspecting it may be a different version from the one in the demo url. Because the full page is not available I'm not sure if 'counting' the number of header items will give me a reference for a column. My best guess is to either use a full javascript API solution or see if there is a setting to add more info.

Comment: I tried with the solution if 'counting' the number of header items could provide me any reference. But, even, that doesn't work, Since, data for all the 'Headers' are coupled together in above section (as shown in the attached image) and there is no proper identifier to segregate the 'Header' specific data.